# How to prove this identity?(perhaps related to partition)

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

How to prove this identity?
$$ \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{x^{n^2}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)} = \frac{1}{\prod_{k \ge 0}(1-x^{5k+1})(1-x^{5k+4})}$$
Maybe the method using generating functions is good.

Comment: I knew the left part of this identity is the generating function of those partitions in whose Young diagrams, the width is larger than the high. But I don't how to relate it to a product in the right and how to relate it to 5. And with the help of Phira, I find a combinatorial proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first of the two Rogers-Ramanujan identities.

The Wikipedia site:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_identities
contains a list of references where you can find proofs.